# Windows 10 & Num Lock Light

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, numlock

I just upgraded a computer to `Windows 10` and it's doing something I've never seen before. If `Num Lock` is on, the light on the keyboard turns on while I'm typing and then turns off after a few seconds of no typing. Although everything seems to be working fine, it's just one of the little annoying nitpick things that drives me crazy. I've looked through the control panel and didn't see anything to turn this "feature" off... Has anyone else run into this and now how to solve it? The keyboard is a `Microsoft Wired Keyboard 200`

Comment: Thats interesting, I have a MIcrosoft Wired Keyboard 3000 and Windows 10 but this does not happen to me.  Can you try a different keyboard?  Maybe install the Microsoft keyboard drivers and see if there is a feature there.  Here is the drivers page from MS http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-au/d/wireless-keyboard-2000

Comment: My bad, the link above was the wireless page, here is the wired http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-au/d/wired-keyboard-200